# Error while deleting the file

Tags: ios, nsfilemanager

While deleting existing the file with this command:

`[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:self.sourceFileName error:&error];`

I got the following error

> Error: ImageIO: CGImageReadCreateDataWithMappedFile  'open' failed '/Users/asdasd/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/DD251D7D-F0AF-40E1-A033-F221623D589D/Library/ScanSession/Source/page3.jpeg
>        error = 2 (No such file or directory)'

This happens while I copied pic from album into app folder. The most interesting thing is that file exists, but not fully copied. Is there a way to check wether file is file operation completed?

Comment: you are not permitted to delete/modify/add any file in the `Library` folder.

Comment: Solved it 2 yars ago. Forgot to post & close the question. It was caused by another thread, where the file was deleted first. I think its one of the standart mutlithreading issues while working with CoreData

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check weather your file & Directory available

```
   for (NSString *filename in files) {
    NSString *path = [yourPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:yourFileName];        
    BOOL isDir;
    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:yourPath isDirectory:&isAvilDir] && isAvilDir){
        NSLog(@"%@ Check is a directory", your path file);  
    }
    else {
        NSLog (@"%@ Check is a file",your path file);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but this won't & didn't help. the key is that file entry exists, but not operable.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem right now, and it seems as though when you delete a file that certain other methods you may have called immediately prior may actually not have completed yet.  I'm considering delaying the actual deletion of files to allow for background processes to complete.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The issue was solved by my teamleader. It was caused by another thread, where the file was deleted first. I think its one of the standart mutlithreading issues while working with CoreData

Answer (score 0):

Solved it 2 yars ago. Forgot to post & close the question. It was caused by another thread, where the file was deleted first. I think its one of the standart mutlithreading issues while working with CoreData